# SSL session cache fails in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, openssl, basehttpserver

I'm trying to set up an HTTPS server using python, and SSL session caching doesn't work. Here's a minimal reproduction. The certificate is a simple self-signed certificate and key that I produced with the openssl command-line.

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl

context = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain("cert.pem", "cert.key")
old_hits = 0
old_misses = 0

class myHTTPHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(s):
        global old_hits,old_misses
        hits = context.session_stats()['hits']
        misses = context.session_stats()['misses']
        hitmiss = "Cache hit" if hits>old_hits else ("Cache miss" if misses>old_misses else "Resumption not requested")
        old_hits = hits
        old_misses = misses
        body = "You requested: {}; {}\n".format(s.path,hitmiss)
        s.send_response(200)
        s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        s.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(body)))
        s.end_headers()
        s.wfile.write(body)

httpd = HTTPServer(('',4434),myHTTPHandler)
httpd.socket = context.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I test this using the following curl command-line:

```
curl -k https://<addr>:4434/ https://<addr>:4434/ https://<addr>:4434/
```

And the result is:

```
You requested: /; Resumption not requested
You requested: /; Cache miss
You requested: /; Cache miss
```

Thanks.

Environment:

- Running on stock Ubuntu
- Python 2.7.12
- OpenSSL 1.0.2g

Comment: Also see the notes at [Session Reuse and Session Caching](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client#Session_Reuse) from the [TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) example on the OpenSSL wiki. You have to enable session caching at the client. While you are twiddling bits, you should use TLS 1.0 and [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) at the client, too.

Comment: The client here is the curl command-line, which has session reuse enabled by default. Looking at the traffic in Wireshark also confirms that the client is attempting session resumption but the server is refusing.